# Ways to grab and store larger amount of text

Tags: macros

A standard way to grab and store a short text (say, a title of a document) is to use something like

```
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}.
```

But if the content to be stored is longer (say, an abstract}, I guess it is considered more elegant to specify it by something like

```
\begin{abstract}
  ...
\end{abstract}
```

on the user side.

So, the question is: what techniques are available to do something like this?  (Some that spring to my mind immediately are: use a `\vbox`, use delimited arguments, use the `environ` LaTeX package, use ConTeXt `\grabbufferdata` (if I am not mistaken as to the name of that macro)...)

I'd be delighted to see all kinds of answers, for various engines (Knuthian vanilla TeX, eTeX, luaTeX) and formats (plain TeX, LaTeX2e, LaTeX3, ConTeXt).

Comment: To be honest, if you are planning to "grab" the environment content in a macro or token register, I'd advise to use the normal "control sequence" syntax. It looks less elegant in the document, but is more honest and less prone to provoke misunderstandings. An environment is supposed to have the semantics that something is executed at the beginning, then the content is executed and then something is executed at the end. Changing that will confuse especially new users, because they can't understand why they can't use `\verb` inside or whatever.

Comment: Good point.  However, I can imagine at least two situations when this is not the case: (i) backward compatibility with existing classes/packages (the case of `abstract`) and (ii) situations when you want to do *both*: typeset *and* store some material for later reuse.

And I wouldn't care too much about `\verb`, if you need to use it, you are probably writing about TeX itself, and that means that you're not a newbie;).  (`\url` is a problem, though.)

Answer (score 19):

The [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package; a little example (defining an environment to collect text and format it between rules and using `\section`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecollection{test}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{atest}[1]
  {\@nameuse{collect}{test}{\par\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill}
    {\par\nobreak\noindent\hrulefill\par\bigskip}
    {\section{#1}}
    {}%
  }
{\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{atest}{example one}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{atest}

\begin{atest}{example two}
\lipsum[2]
\end{atest}

\lipsum[1-6]

\includecollection{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Straight LaTeX2e:

```
\newsavebox{\myabstractbox}
\newenvironment{myabstract}{\lrbox{\myabstractbox}}{\endlrbox}
```

Extract the contents with

```
\usebox{\myabstractbox}
```

Comment: This doesn't store the text, but only its printed representation.

Comment: @egreg: yes, but sometimes this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10):

### LaTeX

If you just want to store the text in form of tokens, like `\title` does, then you can do it with `environ`:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{sabstract}{\global\let\@sabstract\BODY}
```

The environment's content is (locally) stored in the macro `\BODY`, so globally letting `\@sabstract` to it will do the same as `\title` does with `\@title`.

```
\begin{sabstract}
This is it.

With two paragraphs.
\end{sabstract}
```

### Plain TeX

```
\catcode`@=11
\long\def\sabstract#1\endsabstract{\def\@sabstract{#1}}
\catcode`@=12

\sabstract
This is it.

With two paragraphs.
\endsabstract
```

Answer (score 9):

In ConTeXt, `\grabbufferdata` is a low-level command that is only useful to module
writers. At user level, `buffers` should be used to grab and store contents. For
example, store the contents using

```
\startbuffer
    Whatever
\stopbuffer
```

and retreive them using:

```
\getbuffer
```

You may also typeset the contents using

```
\typebuffer
```

which is useful when you want to include verbatim material in tables and
footnotes.

Buffers may be thought of as a clipboard for copy-pasting content; in fact, as
*named* clipboard, which is useful when you want to repeat material in a
document like a presentation or build metapost figures in steps. To get named
buffers, simply store content using

```
\startbuffer[anything]
    This is a named buffer
\stopbuffer
```

and retrieve it using

```
\getbuffer[anything]
```

or

```
\typebuffer[anything]
```

Buffers are more robust than grabbing content using boxes because you do not
need to care about catcodes while grabbing content. (Of course, you need to
worry about them when retreiving content).

```
\startbuffer
  A C file starts with \type{#include<stdio.h>}.
\stopbuffer

\getbuffer
```

works fine even though the content has a `#`. For this reason, buffers are 
used when you want to process some XML inline in a regular TeX document.

Buffers can also be nested. For example:

```
\startbuffer[one]
   Buffer one
   \startbuffer[two]
      Buffer two
   \stopbuffer
\stopbuffer


\getbuffer[one]
\getbuffer[two]
```

(of course, buffer two is only available after buffer one has been
retreived).

In MkIV, `\startbuffer` and `\stopbuffer` can be on the same line

```
\startbuffer[line] #line \stopbuffer
\typebuffer[line]
```

And finally, the contents of a buffer are available at the Lua end (as the
content is stored in memory). Use the Lua function `buffers.getcontent('name')`
to access the contents of the buffer named `name`.

Of course, like any other ConTeXt macro, you may define your own version of
buffers.

```
\definebuffer
  [grabcontent]
  [
    before=...,
    after=...,
  ]
```

and then use them as regular buffers.

```
\startgrabcontent
  A # B C
\stopgrabcontent

\typegrabcontent
```

The `before` and `after` keys are used with `\getgrabcontent`.

Since buffers don't care about their content, they are
an excellent *comment* environment. In fact, the `hiding` environment in ConTeXt
is defined as a buffer.

```
\setupbuffer
  [\v!hiding]
  [\c!before=,
   \c!after=]
```

Comment: I've always wondered about the implementation here: I assume a toks holding material grabbed verbatim? (Perhaps that would make a good question!)

Comment: @Aditya: thank you so much, I expected your comprehensive answer about ConTeXt;).  As usual, I could learn from it...

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm not sure, but I guess that it's some lua trickery, and I'm pretty sure that in MkII it was writing to a temporary file.

Comment: Indeed, in MkII data was written to temp files. The implementation was similar to data grabbing macro from fancyverb package: data was parsed line by line and the grabbed string was compared with `\stopbuffer`. (That was the reason that `\stopbuffer` had to be on a line of its own). In MkIV, the implementation is Lua based, but it is relatively simple (effectively same as plain TeX answer of egreg, but ConTeXt first changes the catcode table to `vrbcatcodes` and uses a configurable stopper; I really don't understand why nested buffers work).

Answer (score 2):

The [scontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scontents) package tries to *imitate* the concept of ConText `buffers` from the LaTeX side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\begin{document}
% If you need a environment version (like a \startbuffer ... \stopbuffer)
\begin{scontents}[store-env=main]
Something for main A.
\end{scontents}

% If you need a macro version (no verbatim)
\Scontents[store-cmd=main]{Something for main B.}

% or a macro with verbatim
\Scontents*[store-cmd=main]{Something for \verb|main C|.}

% Let's print them (like a \getbuffer)
This is first stored in main: \getstored[1]{main}\par
This is third stored in main: \getstored[3]{main}\par

% Print all of stored in main
\foreachsc[sep={\\[10pt]}]{main}

% Print source content (like a \typebuffer)
\typestored[3]{main}\par
\typestored[2]{main}\par
\typestored[1]{main}
\end{document}
```

The environment and starred macro version support *verbatim content*, the environment can be nested but **cannot start and end on the same line**. With both versions (environment and starred) it is also possible to write content to an external file. The non starred macro version has no support for *verbatim content*.

(I leave this answer here only because this post served as general inspiration for `scontents`)

Comment: Unfortunately the `scontents` environment is not extensible (use in a newly defined environment), `VerbatimOut` can be used  instead (although it have to use a temporary file)

Answer (score 1):

Wheee another one for the `#`-rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\dosomething{inside,}
\def\dosomethingelse{and outside the group}
\def\foo#{\bgroup\dosomething\aftergroup\dosomethingelse\let\next= }

\begin{document}
\foo{
  \verb|bar|

  \verb|baz|
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I *think* you have it the wrong way round. The OP wants to know how to turn an environment into a macro argument, and you are showing how to turn a macro argument into an environment ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke: That `\vbox` threw me off. Still, I think it's nice enough to mention.