# Macro: Storage and usage of abstract content does not work in cls

Tags: macros

I got handed a `cls` to use for in a document which produces an `! Undefined control sequence` error when used with `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)`

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@maketitle ...ace {\z@ }}\end {center}\@abstract 
                                                  \vspace {3.0em}\par \vskip...
```

I tried narrowing the problem down and created a simplified `cls` and a corresponding MWE.

The creator of the class seems to try to grab the content of the abstract and store it for use in a modified `maketitle` command. The approach is similar to the one described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70016/44634).

I tried several approaches but was unable to fix the error. Any ideas?

---

### cls

```
\ProvidesClass{test}[2021/03/22 v0.1 Test class]

% Set up basic geometry
\LoadClass[10pt,a4paper,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

% Define title
\let\test@maketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \twocolumn[
    \test@maketitle
    \large%
    \begin{center}{%
      \bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-0.7em}\vspace{\z@}%
    }\end{center}%
    \@abstract%
    \vspace{3.0em}%
  ]
  \thispagestyle{empty}
}

% Change title command
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \begin{center}%
    \let\footnote\thanks%
    {%
      \Large\bfseries%
      \expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}%
      \par%
    }%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {%
      \Large\lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author%
      \end{tabular}%
      \par%
    }%
    \vskip 1em%
    {%
      \large\@date%
    }%
  \end{center}%
  \par\vskip 1.5em%
}

% Renew abstract command to store the abstract
\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{
  \def\@abstract{#1}
}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{test}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{MWE}
\author{raedma}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have redefined `\abstract` to work like `\author` with syntax `\abstract{my abstract here}` so it saves the definition for use later, but you have used it as an environment, in a form where it is typeset directly. You need to delete the definition or use the new vesrion in the document

Comment: Ask the person who made this to fix it. They seem to assume that users write their abstract as `\abstract{text}` which is seldomly the case, most use `\begin/end{abstract}` in which case they need something like the `environ` package to grab the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\@abstract` is used by `\maketitle`, you need to type the abstract *before* `\maketitle` and in the form

```
\abstract{This is the text of the abstract}
```

So the following code should work.

```
\documentclass{test}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{MWE}
\author{raedma}
\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The class might do better and, as part of `\maketitle`, redefine `\abstract` to issue an error message or a warning about the correct syntax and position of `\abstract`.